# Localization Parameters for Bean Validation API in Odd Order

Tags: spring, localization, constraints, bean-validation

On some entity fields I have the following:

`@Size(min = 5, max = 150, message = "validation.error.size")`

My localized message in `messages.properties` is:

`validation.error.size={0} must be between {2} and {1} characters`

I'm wondering why `min` is at index 2 and `max` is at index 1. My only guess currently is that it is alphabetical; with the field name always being at index 0?

Comment: That is the Bean Validation API, not the JPA API (as shown by the package the annotation comes from). http://beanvalidation.org/

Comment: You're right. I'll adjust the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the texual representation for the keys.

```
validation.error.size=${validatedValue} must be between {min} and {max} characters
```

Also you have to use curly braces around the message key string in the validation annotation. other wise it will be interpreted as message

```
@Size(min = 5, max = 150, message = "{validation.error.size}")
```